# window.history.back() shows "Document Expired" page, any way around that?

Tags: javascript, django, internet-explorer, history

Client is asking for the ability for users to go back to a page full of search results after clicking on a result.  Right now it's a simple jQuery call:

```
$('a.detail-back-button').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

This shows a "Document Expired" page in Firefox, however.  I know it's there for security, but the client wants this implemented anyways.  I've done some searching around and I've found a php solution to the problem...

```
session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire')
```

...but this is a Django-based web site.  Are there any other solutions?

**UPDATE 02/21/13**

The solution below works but only for browsers that aren't IE.  IE8/9/10 doesn't seem to re-request the previous page.  Is there an IE workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the by definition non-idempotent nature of `POST`ed requests. I.e. a `POST` is an action which has an effect, and is thus unsafe to repeat. To prevent this from happening accidentally, some browsers show a placeholder page with a confirmation message before resubmitting the original form.

The most reliable solution -possibly the only one- is to submit your form using the `GET` method instead, which makes sense anyway.

Comment: This solution worked but seem IE8/9/10 doesn't want to re-request the previous page.  Any ideas?

Comment: Cookie monster disagrees .... django formtools have CookieWizardView... it uses POST and it is REALLY annoying to fix the back button in this case ...